# how to setup django database accessed from 3 apps

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have 3 apps in a project. What I want to do are 2 things.

(1) I want to setup each apps to access same database(Read & Write).

I have no idea that I have to have same models.py each of my apps. If so, how can I migrate database. I tried it, but one app which was used to do migrate command success database access. But other 2 apps couldn't access database.

And I tried to make simbolic link of models.py and migrations directory to each apps directories. But it didn't work too.

(2) I want to use django authentication system to each of my apps.

App1 (For Enduser) - (email, password)

App2 (For Service provider) - (ID, password)

App3 (For System Administrator) - (ID (different from App2), password)

I can use django user authentication system from 1 app. But I want to make authentication system to 3 apps from different urls. App1 is a webview based app that use django via rest framework. App2 and App3 are web application (different url and port). Can I make it on using django?

Would you give me some advice please?

Comment: All apps in a project use the same database, there's no need to copy or link models files.

Comment: Thank you for an advice. What I am confusing is how can I configure each models.py. I must have 3 models.py if I have 3 apps. Which models.py should I use when I want to migrate database? I am confusing now...

Comment: If you're not defining any new models in each app, why do you need to have anything at all in models.py?

Comment: Thank you for reply. But I don't make sense. For example, if I add any model from app1's models.py, do you mean I don't have to add this model's definition to app2 and app3's models.py? If so, how can I access this model from app2 and app3?

Comment: You import it, like you do with any other code.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you for your kindness advise. If you can, I want to know about (2).